# Custom prediction function doesn't give back mean-controlled variables in R

Tags: r, function, regression, scatter-plot, predict

I'm trying to create a quick function for generating prediction data from regressions that also controls for the mean of other predictors, but I'm hitting a dead end on the second iteration of my code. The first version works perfectly. Below is what it looks like.

```
#### Line Data Function ####
gen.line <- function(fit,x,name,l=200){
  
  #### Load DPLYR ####
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(dplyr))
  
  #### Generate X Data ####
  df <- data.frame(
    x = seq(
      min(x),
      max(x),
      length.out=l
    )
  ) %>% 
    setNames(name) %>%
    as_tibble()
  
  #### Predict Y ####
  p <- predict(fit,newdata=df)
  
  #### Create line.data tibble ####
  line.data <- tibble(
    !!name := df[[name]], # this prevents $ operator
    y = p
  )
  
  #### Return Seq and Pred Data ####
  return(line.data)
}

#### Get Data ####
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(100,0,8) + 50
y <- 50 + cos(x) + rnorm(100,sd=.5) 
fit <- lm(y ~ cos(x))

#### Generate Line ####
plot(x,y)
lines <- gen.line(
  fit,
  x,
  "x"
)
```

Which gives me the right prediction line:

[image]

The issue is when I try to generalize this to include any other predictors that are set to their mean to produce partial effects plots. The code I have so far looks like this:

```
#### Mean-Controlled Version ####
gen.line <- function(fit, # regression
                     x, # variable of interest
                     name, # name of variable
                     l=200, # length of xseq
                     extra_vars=list()){ # other vars
  #### Load DPLYR ####
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(dplyr))
  
  #### Generate X Data ####
  df <- data.frame(
    x = seq(
      min(x),
      max(x),
      length.out=l
    )
  ) %>% 
    setNames(name) %>%
    as_tibble()
  
  #### Add extra variables ####
  for(var in names(extra_vars)) {
    df <- df %>% 
      mutate(!!var := mean(extra_vars[[var]]))
  }
  
  #### Predict Y ####
  p <- predict(fit,newdata=df)
  
  #### Create line.data tibble ####
  line.data <- tibble(
    !!name := df[[name]],
    y = p
  )
  
  #### Return Seq and Pred Data ####
  return(line.data)
}


#### Get Data ####
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(100,0,8) + 50
z <- runif(100,0,8) + 30
y <- 50 + cos(x) + cos(z) + rnorm(100,sd=.5) 

#### Fit Data ####
fit <- lm(y ~ cos(x) + cos(z))
summary(fit)

#### Generate Line ####
gen.line(
  fit, x, "x", extra_vars = list(z = z)
)
```

When I run the last line of code, it gives me a constant `y` value, which is clearly wrong (it's prediction data so it should change based on the `x` value. See below output.

```
# A tibble: 200 × 2
       x     y
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  50.0  50.0
 2  50.0  50.0
 3  50.1  50.0
 4  50.1  50.0
 5  50.2  50.0
 6  50.2  50.0
 7  50.2  50.0
 8  50.3  50.0
 9  50.3  50.0
10  50.4  50.0
# ℹ 190 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure there's a problem? The code looks 'fine' to me (although I definitely could've missed something). If you print out all of the y values (e.g. `print(n = 200, gen.line(fit = fit, x = x, name = "x", extra_vars = list(z = z)))` you can see that not all of them are 50.

Comment: Oh weird I totally missed that. I guess if I had actually plotted that out it woulda been more obvious.

Comment: No worries; glad you 'fixed' your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As Jared noted, the issue was simply that I didn't inspect the data well enough. Plotting the code directly shows that the mean-controlled partial effects plots lines still show up.

```
plot(x,y)
lines(lines)
```

[image]